# IE element width to min-content

Tags: html, css

I have the following container holding both an image and a text element.

```
<div class="container">
    <img id="image" src="http://dummyimage.com/200">
    <span class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </span>
</div>
```

The desired behaviour is that the div should wrap to the width of the image, and therfore keep the text correctly wrapped underneath. This also needs to be flexible as content is dynamic and image width is not known in advance.

You can do this elegantly enough in Firefox and Chrome using min-content.

```
.container {
    /*Other style stuff up here*/
    width: -moz-min-content;
    width: -webkit-min-content;
}
```

[Jsfiddle of above - works perfectly in FF and Chrome.](http://jsfiddle.net/h3Qen/)

**My Problem:**
Internet Explorer has no min-content (or equivalent that I can find) which means it is the text not the image which determines the containers width.

Is there any similarly elegant way of achieving this in Internet Explorer?

If not how can i restructure the html/css to allow for cross broser compatibilty for the same behaviour?

Comment: What versions of IE do you need to support?

Comment: Well i guess ideally all of them :). Would be very happy with 8+, but latest at a minimum.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As mentioned by someone else you can use -ms-grid-columns.  You just add a div around your content with IE only CSS.  To other browsers the CSS is ignored and shouldn't affect your layout (unless you're applying CSS to all div elements like padding/margin in which case stop doing that).

## HTML

```
<div id="stupidIE">
    <div class="container">
        <img id="image" src="http://dummyimage.com/200" alt="">
        <span class="text">
            Cupcake ipsum dolor sit. 
            Amet chocolate carrot cake oat cake bear claw croissant.
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.container 
{
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    padding: 0.3em;
    width: -moz-min-content;
    width: -webkit-min-content;
}
#stupidIE
{
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: min-content;
}
```

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LRYSp/

Tested in Chrome and IE11.  But it should work in other browsers.  However I don't think it will render correctly in IE9 and below.

Comment: I like your solution. I would advise against bashing IE. Unlike Chrome, it does not scan your entire file system.

Comment: @VladimirKocjancic Wasn't so much as bashing as dealing with frustrating non-intuitive elements.  I actually saw the original post a few minutes after it was posted then spent an hour trying to figure out how to correctly use the -ms-grid and it's elements.  The MSDN isn't very helpful and the attributes don't work like you expect them to.  For instance if you apply the -ms-grid and columns property to the container you then have to put the child elements in a containing div or they overlap.  But then the container stretches to 100% even though child elements have the right width.

Comment: @VladimirKocjancic   So I wasn't bashing IE, I was just venting frustration.  Same way I call chrome stupid after I battle with a dumb concept for hours.

Comment: @Stack of Pancakes I agree, IE wants to do things its own way which kind of forces you to approach it as a problem. Id messed around with ms-grid on the container but hadnt made the leap to applying it to the grand-parent. It works perfectly and requires minimal alteration to my preexisting setup, short of an '-ie-min-content' this has to be the best solution.

Comment: @StackofPancakes I wish I could upvote this more than once

Answer (score 3):

@Stack_of_Pancakes solution is lacking in that it adds an extra div which is a block element and spans the entire width, whereas the original width:min-content doesn't have this flaw. 
It can be fixed:

HTML: (intact)

```
<div class="container">
    <img id="image" src="http://dummyimage.com/200" alt="">
    <span class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    padding: 0.3em;
    width: -moz-min-content;
    width: -webkit-min-content;
    display: -ms-inline-grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: min-content;
}
.container > span:nth-child(2) 
{
    -ms-grid-row:2;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L28s7txr/6

Answer (score 0):

a bit of jquery?

```
$(function() {
    $('.container').width($('img#image').width());
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h3Qen/3/)**

Comment: I like it and it works. If I cannot find a pure html/css solution then I cant imagine a cleaner alternative than this.