# Expand body to fit all content

Tags: html, css

If content is wider then browser window, body and html tags remain same width as the screen, and if you scroll to the side, some elements will not go beyond body. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ok8axrjo/3/) to display what I mean. The content box is wider then the screen, and if you scroll to the right, header doesn't expand beyond one screen width.

For now, I was able to fix it by width: max-content.

```
body {
    width: -moz-max-content;
    width: -webkit-max-content;
}
```

However, this only works in Chrome and FF, and not in IE.

Are there different, better-supported solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicated to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160267/ie-element-width-to-min-content

Answer (score 0):

Try this css code

```
body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0
}


.header{
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
   }
```

see demo http://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/ok8axrjo/

Comment: right, but header still doesn't expand beyond one screen length

Comment: add width: 100% in header

Comment: nope, still the same. May be i'm not explaining it right. Content is much wider then the screen, so if you scroll to the right, header will remain the width of one screen, instead of expanding to fit all space available

Answer (score 0):

Under my understanding, I think set `position: fixed` and `width:100%` to header will work. But you may need to adjust `margin-top` for content.

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xpqcLo1k/1/)