# make word-break:break-all work without width?

Tags: css

im trying to make word-break:break-all work without width is that possible? i have tried almost every fix and nothing worked. (except when i put a certain amount of width e.g width:25ch;) however it looks terrible when the text is long. here is my code

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans';
 body {
  margin: 0px;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.contentwrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: table;
}
hr {
  width: 100%;
}
.card {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: box-shadow .25s;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)
}
.card .card-image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.card .card-content {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
}
.card .card-action {
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.2);
  padding: 20px;
}
span.information {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body style="background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242)" ;>
  <div class="contentwrapper">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <span class="information">
    THIS A TESTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSadsssssssssssssssssssss
    </span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        EPIC
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: example of what i mean]

edit:the image is dynamic thats why i cant add width to the element :/

Comment: Why can't you apply `width` to anything? The `word-break` is working, but only if it hits the window width since that is the thing that contains an actual width.

Comment: if i add width to it and the placehold changes to something like 600x600 then it looks terrible. my website is dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.contentwrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 30px;
    display: table;

}
.card {
    transition: box-shadow .25s;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: min-content;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12)
}
.card .card-content{
    text-transform: lowercase;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
}
.card .card-action{
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(160,160,160,0.2);
    padding: 20px;
}
span.information {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentwrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="information">
       THIS A TESTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSadsssssssiodfjiojsidfjiosjdoifjosdjfoisjdfsjdfijoisdjfsfsssssssssssssss
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action">
      EPIC
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I suggest using `width: min-content` to accomplish this.

Comment: BEAUTIFUL! exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Note that you can't use `min-content` in IE11 / Edge or Opera: http://caniuse.com/#search=min-content

Comment: is there any alternative for it? when using edge or opera or ie11?

Comment: @flex See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160267/ie-element-width-to-min-content for a solution to this issue.

Comment: @StardustGogeta does it apply to opera too? or only edge and IE

Comment: @flex Check the link that Derek gave, Opera is supported. However, Opera Mini is not and likely has no alternative other than explicitly giving a `width`.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider restructuring your html so its a bit simpler:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/axb6s76r/5/)

```
<div class="contentwrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  <span class="information">
       THIS A TESTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSadsssssssiodfjiojsidfjiosjdoifjosdjfoisjdfsjdfijoisdjfsfsssssssssssssss
   </span>
</div>
<div class="card-action">
  EPIC
</div>
```

Then, because you are already using `display: table` for the container, you can take advantage of `display: table-caption;` for the text:

```
span.information {
  word-break: break-all;
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
```

Comment: if i could add width then i would of done that. but i'm only using 300x300 as an example. the website is dynamic meaning it could be 100x100 or 1000x1000

Comment: thanks for taking time to edit but umm now it breaks every single word..

Comment: In the fiddle? What browser?

Comment: in the fiddle it works perfect. but in my localhost it breaks every letter.. pretty weird

Comment: Did you restructure your html like I suggested? It won't work if you don't.

Comment: well if i restructure it like you said it will work but it looks terrible now. it has no box shadow or anything

Comment: is it possible to achieve what you did without removing some of my classes?

Comment: Because you haven't applied your styles to the new structure accordingly. You were nesting divs without any additional content in them. Apply the same styles to a single container instead.

Comment: i'm sorry i'm confused what do you mean by that? in your source code you removed my card and card action and card image